# Enabling antialiasing drawing Primitives Monogame

Tags: c#, monogame, hlsl

I'm trying to draw a triangle primitive using Monogame, and enabling AA.  However, I am getting this result- [Jagged Triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCbXW.png)

I want a triangle with smooth Anti-Aliased edges.

Here is my code, where I've already enabled AA and set everything properly (maybe not though, as the lines are still extremely jagged)-

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Game1
{
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        VertexBuffer vertexBuffer;

        BasicEffect basicEffect;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {

            graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;
            graphics.GraphicsProfile = GraphicsProfile.HiDef;

            graphics.ApplyChanges();

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            basicEffect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice);

             VertexPositionColor[] vertices = new[]{new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(160.0f, 200.0f, 0), Color.Red), new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(200.0f, 140.0f, 0), Color.Green), new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(250.0f, 200.0f, 0), Color.Blue) };

            vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(GraphicsDevice, typeof(VertexPositionColor), 3, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
            vertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionColor>(vertices);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            basicEffect.World = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0, 0, 1); 
            basicEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;

            GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);

            RasterizerState rasterizerState = new RasterizerState();
            rasterizerState.CullMode = CullMode.None;
            GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rasterizerState;

            foreach (EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();
                GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 1);
            }

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: The best you can achieve is +/- one pixel.  When you have a diagnol line, the line resolution is the spacing of the pixels.  Changing the angle of the line to 45 degrees will give some improvements

Comment: So you're saying there's no way to draw non-jagged imperfect triangles in monogame?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to render the primitive to a render target twice the size and then, render the target to the screen at half size.

The resize filtering will handle the anti-aliasing for you.